# override navigation of datagridview using enter key

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do you override the enter key in a datagridview so that it will set focus to the next column instead to the next row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is handle the KeyDown event of the DataGridView and in the handler, check if the current key pressed is an Enter key. If so, just set the CurrentCell of the DataGridView to the next cell (also check if this is the last cell in the row, in that case, move to the first cell of the next Row.)

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim numCols As Integer = DataGridView1.ColumnCount
    Dim numRows As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount
    Dim currCell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.CurrentCell
    If currCell.ColumnIndex = numCols - 1 Then
      If currCell.RowIndex < numRows - 1 Then
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item(0, currCell.RowIndex + 1)
      End If
    Else
      DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item(currCell.ColumnIndex + 1, currCell.RowIndex)
    End If
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub DbGDetail_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DbGDetail.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub DbGDetail_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DbGDetail.CellEndEdit

    SendKeys.Send("{up}")
    SendKeys.Send("{Tab}")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the help I needed to get me going in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/b4d61bfb-5fa1-4e97-a419-a35ef0900ba6/) specifically in 
Rong-Chun Zhang's feedback on subclassing `DataGridView` to override  `ProcessDialogKey`. I morphed his work to meet my own requirements in the example below.

Objective: Strictly speaking it was to keep the focus in the Grid from jumping from the last cell at end of last row to the next row when ENTER key is pressed, only in cases where focus was leaving any cell on the second-to-last row.

Background: I'd enabled the Grid option for allowing users to create new rows in the database, so to make it simple for them the default Grid behavior is that a new empty row always gets added at the bottom, and as soon as the user even inadvertantly moves onto it, a new empty row gets created in the database. Users typically tap ENTER after finishing edits in any cell, so there wasnt a good way for the user to end their edit to the last cell at the bottom without creating a new blank row.

Note that in this case I'm just leaving the CurrentCell where it is, but it can be re-assigned before the call to 'return true'.

```
public class DataGridViewAddRow : DataGridView
{

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {

        //cell is in Edit mode

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {

            if (this.CurrentCell.RowIndex == this.Rows.Count-2)
            {                            
                return true;
            }

        }

        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGridView focus to the Next Cell or Column when Enter key is Pressed for VB.net :

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewX1.CellEndEdit

If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1 Then
  DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Item(0, DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1)
Else
    SendKeys.Send("{up}")
    SendKeys.Send("{right}")
End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Public Class CustomDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView

```
<System.Security.Permissions.UIPermission( _
    System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, _
    Window:=System.Security.Permissions.UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows)> _
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey( _
    ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean

    ' Extract the key code from the key value. 
    Dim key As Keys = keyData And Keys.KeyCode

    ' Handle the ENTER key as if it were a RIGHT ARROW key. 
    If key = Keys.Enter Then
        Return Me.ProcessTabKey(keyData)
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)

End Function

<System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission( _
    System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags:= _
    System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)> _
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDataGridViewKey( _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) As Boolean

    ' Handle the ENTER key as if it were a RIGHT ARROW key. 
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Return Me.ProcessTabKey(e.KeyData)
    End If

    Return MyBase.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e)

End Function
```

End Class